# How to increase resolution in Adobe flash

Tags: adobe-flash

Im making an animated gif in flash,  its having width and height 1024px*730px ,  when i convert into animated gif, its clarity is too low.

when i try to increase the resolution, the width and height is increasing..

[image: when i change resolution width and height is changing]

**How to increase the resolution without changing the width and height..**

Comment: Read this: [The Myth of DPI](http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/mythdpi.html)

Answer (score 1):

That's simply not how it works.

When you export a GIF the resolution won't matter, the size in pixels will.

If you want your animation to be sharper, it has to be larger. Changing resolution and keeping the same width/height will not make any difference in the quality of the image.